# Spring util:map injection with @resource

Tags: java, spring, annotations

This should be simple but I don't manage to get it working.

I have field annotated with @resource:

```
public class foo {
  @Resource(name = "configMap")
  private Map<String, String> config;
}
```

In applicationContext.xml I have (to be populated with Maven:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<util:map id="configMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="url" value="${url}"></entry>
</util:map>
```

But at run time this doesn't work, the config field remains null. Any advices?

Edit: I am using Spring 3.0 and it is an existing project so I can't tell right away if there is some bizarre config elsewhere preventing this from working.

Comment: How is the "foo" instance created? Could you be creating another instance of it by mistake?

Comment: That has to be the case. I'll take a new look at that code soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As waxwing suggested, the instance was not created properly.

Answer (score 1):

Have You included the context name space to your beans definition ?

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
```